# Duplicate resources: how do android namespace in layouts, customviews and attributes work?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, custom-attributes

According to [Google training docs on custom views](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view),

> Once you define the custom attributes, you can use them in layout XML
> files just like built-in attributes. The only difference is that your
> custom attributes belong to a different namespace.

But I am getting a "Error: Duplicate resources" when I try to use this.
My layout file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:searchview="http://schemas.android.com
    /apk/com.kana_tutor.kana_utils.SearchView"
        xmlns:simplespinner="http://schemas.android.com
    /apk/com.kana_tutor.kana_utils.SimpleSpinner"
         ...>
    
        <com.kana_tutor.kana_utils.SearchView
          ...
            searchview:textColor="/@color/red"
            />
    
        <com.kana_tutor.kana_utils.SimpleSpinner
            ...
            simplespinner:textColor="@color/textview_background"
            />
        ...
```

I put the attributes in two separate files:
searchview_attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="SearchView">
        <attr name="textColor" format = "reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

simplespinners_attrs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="simplespinner">
        <attr name="textColor" format = "reference|string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

But the IDE says:

> [attr/textColor] /.../simplespinner_attrs.xml [attr/textColor]
> /.../searchview_attrs.xml: Error: Duplicate resources

As I read the docs, I should be able to have sAm I misunderstanding "belong to a different namespace" or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you trying to implement your own views or use the ones from com.kana_tutor.kana_utils ?

Comment: I guess you could say "both."  I'm creating/using com.kana_tutor.kana_utils.  Mostly I'm trying to rearn kotlin/android.

Comment: Do they provide a library that you could use? so it would be like implementation "com.kana_tutor.kana_utils:1.0.0"

Comment: um... I am they.  This isn't my first custom view but it is the first where I've tried to use multiple different custom views in the same layout so I haven't run into this problem before.  I haven't put this on Maven because I'm still writing it and in any case don't know if it would be of general interest.  The question however is of interest judging by the number of mentions of similar problems I see on the net.  Hopefully someone on the site has some deeper understanding of this.